# How to properly create a square and cube function?

Tags: c++

I am learning how to use functions in C++ and am working on a square root and cube function, however I am having issues upon running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double squareit(double);
double cubeit(double);

int main() 
{
    double inputnumber;
    cout << "Enter a floating point number\n";
    cin >> inputnumber;
    cout << "Your number squared is " << squareit(inputnumber) << endl;
    cout << "Your number cubed is " << cubeit(inputnumber) << endl;
}
double squareit(double in)
{
    double x;

    return x * x;
}
double cubeit(double in)
{
    double x;

    return x * x * x;
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: Your compiler will most likely be able to point you in the right direction here with adequate warning options.

Comment: _"I am having issues"_.  Alright.  Have you told us what issues you are having?

Comment: Your functions appear to be calculating the square / cube of an uninitialized local variable, instead of the parameter passed to the function.  This is the equivalent of my wife giving me her mug and asking for more coffee, and I give her back a birdcage containing -17 elephants.

Comment: It may help you to [look at the warnings your compiler is giving you](https://godbolt.org/z/oKx13PE6r).  Do you have questions about what these warnings are telling you?  Do you agree with what the warnings are saying about your code?

Comment: Why not `return in * in;` and `return in * in * in;`?

Answer (score 3):

You have got the concept correct, but have forgotten to assign the local variable the value of the parameter.

instead of

```cpp
double cubeIt(double number) { //note the naming convention
    double x;     //x has an undefined value
    return x * x * x;
}
```

you need:

```cpp
double cubeIt(double number) {
    double x = number;
    return x * x * x;
}
```

or better still:

```cpp
double cubeIt(double number) {
    return number * number * number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually handle this in a general sense with a template:

```
template<typename T>
T square(const T& val) {
    return val*val
}

template<typename T>
T cube(const T& val) {
    return val*val*val
}
```

Then it will work with any data type that support `operator*`.